# Export iCal from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to be able to export an iCal file from my calendar. I can't get it to work, it does not start to "download" the file.

Right now I just try to get one meeting, but later on I will make a for loop to get all the meetings in the database to the iCal file, but I just want to check if it works, but it does not.

This below is my method in the controller and later the jQuery to call the method.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToICalendar()
{
    var ctx = new OruBloggenDbContext();

    var meetings = ctx.Meetings.FirstOrDefault(u => u.MeetingID == 1);

    var icalStringbuilder = new StringBuilder();        

    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("PRODID:-//MyTestProject//EN");
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");

    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:" + meetings.MeetingTitle);
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("CLASS:PUBLIC");
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("CREATED:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + meetings.MeetingDesc);
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", meetings.MeetingStartDate));
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", meetings.MeetingEndDate));
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("SEQUENCE:0");
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("UID:" + Guid.NewGuid());

    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
    icalStringbuilder.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(icalStringbuilder.ToString());

    return this.File(bytes, "text/calendar", "ical.ics");
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(document)

        .on("click", "#icalBtn", function () {
            exportiCal();
        });

    function exportiCal() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/MeetingCalendar/AddToICalendar',
            type: "POST",
            //data: { downloadFileName = "thisEvent.ics" },

            success: function (data) {
                alert("hejejje");
            }

        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: are the bytes being sent to your client? (inside the data variable of success function)

Comment: I'd recommend using the ready-made library for the purpose of creating iCal entries: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ical.Net/ (source code: https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net)

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing downloads is because you can't download files via AJAX. Instead of being delivered to a file on your computer's disk, the downloaded content is going into the `data` variable in your "success" function.

To solve it, instead of using AJAX, make your action method accept GET requests and just user a regular hyperlink to link the user to it:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddToICalendar()
{
 //..etc
```

and

```
<a href="/MeetingCalendar/AddToICalendar" id="icalBtn">Download to iCalendar</a>
```

You can remove all your jQuery code.

---

N.B. Logging that `data` value to the console (instead of just alerting meaningless junk) - or using your browser's network tools to see what is going on - would have let you see that, and you might have seen the problem sooner...maybe you need to do a bit more debugging in future.